# How to get the parameters variables and display them

Tags: java, oop, input, inputstream

So I will write an example below to show you what im talking about, but basically i want to grab one of the variables inside the parameters of the method for example.

```
public void methodName(int x, int y){
x = x+ 40;
}
```

so how would i display x in the main method like this

```
public static main(String args[]){

}
```

Comment: `x` is local to the method `methodName`.

Comment: display = print to the console? Cant you "sout" it in the method "methodName"?

Answer (score 1):

All primitives are passed by value in Java, so you cannot get x out of its scope, however you can return its value by adding a return type.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables have a certain "scope", in this case the scope of x and y is the method `methodName`. They only can be addressed inside this method and are not available outside of it. You sort of "define" the variables in the method-head.

In order to use variables within several methods, you need "static variables" or "instance variables". Static variables exist without an actual object, while instance variables exist within a created instance of a class object.